# ID attribute returns null on android device with Titanium

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I searched on SO and others to find a solution in vain. I created a `TableView` in XML with an ID `table` and populated it dynamically (by creating several `TableViewRows` and `TextFields` into them).

The issue is the following: when I try to add all the created items programmatically with `$.table.add(row)`, **I have the expected result on browser but a `NullPointerException` on Android** device.

I made some tests in my code to see what is returning `null` and found that the ID attribute `$.table` was the problem. What happen in Android and how to fix it ?

**mytable.xml:**

```
<Alloy>
    <Window id="win_container">
        <View id="wrapper">
            <!-- The TableView -->
            <TableView id="table" />
        </View>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

**mytable.js:**

```
for (...) {
    // create TableViewRows
    row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow ({
        className: "row",
        ...
    });

    // create several TextFields in one TableViewRow
    for (...) {
        tf = Ti.UI.createTextField ({
            ...
        });
        // add TextFields to the TableViewRow
        row.add(tf);
    }

    // add TableViewRows to table
    $.table.add(row);    ///  <----- '$.table' returns 'null'
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO the error is because of `add` method you are using to add rows in table.

To add a row to a `tableView` you can use following two methodology :

1. Use [`appendRow`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableView-method-appendRow) method of `tableView` : Replace your `$.table.add(row);` with `$.table.appendRow(row);`
2. Push all the rows in an array and then add it to `tableView` using [`setData`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableView-method-setData) method. Your code will look something like :

   ```
   var dataRows = [];
   for (...) {
     // create TableViewRows
     row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow ({
       className: "row",
       ...
     });

     // create several TextFields in one TableViewRow
     for (...) {
       tf = Ti.UI.createTextField ({
        ...
       });
       // add TextFields to the TableViewRow
       row.add(tf);
     }

     dataRows.push(row);
   }

   // add TableViewRows to table
   $.table.setData(dataRows);
   ```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I used the first solution with the method `appendRow()`, and it resolved my issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a “shot in the dark” - but I had a problem with an id called “private”. I had to rename my id to “isPrivate” - so I guess some of these cannot be “reserved names”. I have not checked this - just found out by quick trial-and-error. But perhaps “table” is a similar reserved word?

Comment: Even if I changed its id name, the stacktrace displayed the same error, but thank you anyway. This is a good advice to keep in mind.